# How to pass this Jasmine test 'should recover on fetch error'

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am learning Jasmine. I am having trouble passing a test.

The **it()** below is within a describe of Records, so Records should recover on fetch error. I replaced the expected JSON object with 'Object here', for this post. That's not the issue and its sensitive data.

I'm at the moment getting a fail of 'Expected spy log to have been called'. I assume this has something to do with running a console.log? but when I insert a console.log I get the fail 'Expected spy log to not be called. So this has me very confused.I certainly could be looking at it wrong completely.

My code is just a fetch, returning data from a function called **retrieve()**. That function is being exported, and imported here to be used in the test.

```
it('should recover on fetch error', function(done){
window.path = "http://localhost:3000/recordszzz";
spyOn(console, "log").and.callFake(function(){});

function check(output) {
  window.path = "http://localhost:3000/records";
  expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
  console.log.calls.reset();
  retrieve().then(function(output){
    var expected = {Object here};
    expect(output).toEqual(expected);
    expect(console.log).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    done();
  });
}

retrieve().then(check);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue, and it turns out that the expected result was never coming back. It's a very specific issue in the code. On a .catch, I do console.log the error, ..and simply re try the fetch with a corrected URL request.